# nginx starting but isn't listening on port 80

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have an ubuntu server 14.04 VPS that currently has apache2 serving up a static website. I am switching over to nginx to serve up a couple of nodejs sites.

I installed nginx

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

And am using the default config

```
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I confirm apache2 isn't running causing problems

```
$ sudo service apache2 status
 * apache2 is not running
```

I start nginx and confirm it's status

```
$ sudo service nginx status
 * nginx is running
```

But yet hitting the `sudo netstat -natp` and `sudo fuser 80/tcp` all brought up nothing.

I have my site configured in /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.tld and then linked to sites-enabled.

Still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the process of writing the question and reproducing the steps I figured out what the problem was.

I had created and edited my sites-available server in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.tld`

Then to enable the site, I was in the directory `/etc/nginx/` when in my tired state created the link into the sites-enabled folder by running `ln -s sites-available/mysite.tld sites-enabled/mysite.tld`.

It wasn't until this morning that I realized I had created a bad link when I couldn't vim into the sites-enabled linked version.

Doing an `rm` on the bad link and then using absolute paths for the whole thing `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.tld /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.tld` then a subsequent restart of nginx now shows it listening on port 80 as expected.

*tl-dr;* sometimes it's best to just go to bed and look at it in the morning